# CakePHP: How to organize repeatable forms?

Tags: cakephp, organization, reusability

I have and add/edit form that adds/edits depending on whether there is an id passed.

This model is accessed by three different types of users in 3 completely different situations - different controllers, different menus, different breadcrumbs, different everything. Yet, the form is the same, the logic is the same.

So essentially I have 2 problems - repeating view form and repeating controller code.

I tried to put it in a element, but then I have to pass a variable for the `action` of the form to point to different controllers. And if i have the same action and use the same controller, then I have to have some kind of `referer()` and it's almost impossible to pass all the different data for breadcrumbs, menus, sidebars etc. i am missing something major in   planning it out.

How should I organize my code with the idea to have minimum code and minimum overhead since my app is changing by the day, and i don't want to be updating 3 places and forget some of them etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse controller logic by [creating a component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) (or by placing logic in `AppController`):

```
// controllers/first_controller.php
class FirstController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('MyForm');

    public function firstAction($id = null) {
        $this->MyForm->processForm(/* params */); // inserts reusable logic
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

(Repeat for `SecondController::secondAction()` and `ThirdController::thirdAction()`.)

---

You can reuse view logic by creating elements:

```
// views/first/first_action.ctp
$this->Html->addCrumb('First');
echo $this->Html->tag('h2', 'First');
$this->element('my_form', array(/* params */)); // inserts reusable logic
```

(Repeat for other views.)

---

> I tried to put it in a element, but then I have to pass a variable for the action of the form to point to different controllers.

You can access `$this->params` from inside an element, saving you from having to pass in trivial things like the current action.

Comment: so i would pass data like that: `$this->MyForm->processForm($this->data, $id)` and then from the component, i would have `function($data, $id){` is that right?

Comment: also, how do I return different flashes? and manage different outcomes? like if it fails on step one, i have to return `$result['stats'] = 'fail'; $result['reason']='step1'; $result['flashMessage'] = 'error finding object with this id'; ` ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass in any parameters you define - however, try using `debug($this)` from the component.. you might find things like `$this->data` are already there.

Comment: If you capture the result from your component (ie. `$result = $this->MyForm->processForm()`), then you can do post-processing on the returned data (ie. `if (!$result['stats']) { $this->redirect($result['flashMessage']) }`)

Comment: I noticed that I can still do `$this->controller->set('var', $var);` which solves some of the problems. I noticed that I can't however use models such as `$this->Model->getById($id)`. After all most of the logic is tied to database runs and that's most of what I am trying to make reusable. Confused.

Comment: For example, I saw something like, `$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');` is this okay to use it?

Comment: Yeah, they do that in the [core components](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php#L820) after all. ClassRegistry won't cause a performance hit if the class has already been loaded either.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I wrote and let me know what you think? It works just like it is wanted and expected, but just in case. I put it in the update at the end. Would be enormously thankful!